# Can't add product to customer wishlist

Tags: magento-1.9

I have the code in my REST api:

```
protected function _create(array $filteredData)
{
    $customerId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

    if (!$customer) Mage::log("Customer with '$customerId' id not found",null,'error.log',true);// throw exception

    $requestData = $this->getRequest()->getBodyParams();
    $productId = isset($requestData['id']) ? $requestData['id'] : null;
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($requestData['id']);

    if (!$productId) Mage::log("Product with '$productId' id not found",null,'error.log',true);// throw exception

    /** @var IntegerNet_PamonoWishlist_Model_Wishlist $wishList */
    $wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);
    $wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();
    foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item)
    {
        if($item->getId() === $productId)
        {
            return 'OK';
        }
    }

    $item = $wishList->addNewItem($product);
    $log = sprintf(
        'Item has "%s" type, it is %sempty, its content is: "%s"',
        gettype($item),
        empty($item) ? '' : 'not ',
        json_encode($item)
    );
    Mage::log($log, null, 'messages.log', true);
    $wishList->save();

    return 'OK';
}
```

After save, have no items in my wishlist.
I `messages.log` have:

```
Item has "object" type, it is not empty, its content is: "{}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with store.
So I've added store to request headers and load required store in magento:

```
protected function loadStore()
{
    $storeCode = $this->getRequest()->getHeader('store');

    $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeCode, 'code');
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
}
```

I've put `$this->loadStore();` in the top of each method.